# Htaccess add and force trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having some trouble with my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^about\/$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about?$ /about/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^contact\/$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact?$ /contact/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/gallery\/$ /loc-gallery.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/gallery?$ /$1/gallery/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/location\/$ /loc-location.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/location?$ /$1/location/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/contact\/$ /loc-contact.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/contact?$ /$1/contact/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/$ /loc-home.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

The problem is that if i want to access:

```
http://example.com/about
http://example.com/contact
```

i am not redirected to

```
`http://example.com/about/` and `http://example.com/contact/`
```

and when i try to access `http://example.com/` i am redirected to `http://example.com//`

What i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access http://example.com/ i am redirected to http://example.com// is happening because of this line :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

It will match the empty URI because of this regex `^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$` 
it means match if `([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)` then or not `?` .

It should look like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

I also sumerized your code and fixed some issues like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about(\/)?$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact(\/)?$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/gallery(\/)?$ /loc-gallery.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/location(\/)?$ /loc-location.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/contact(\/)?$ /loc-contact.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/$ /loc-home.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Clear browser cache and test it , if it is ok change `R` to `R=301` to get permanent redirection